# converting XMI to XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi

I am trying to parse `xmi:type` in the `node`. But not able to successfully do so. I am attaching the input file (uml - xmi format), my xslt input and the output I got (xml format). I want to modify the output to write a line whenever I see "`xmi:type = uml:OpaqueAction`". I am able to access the "name" present in the same line but not the `xmi:type`. Not sure why

UML-XMI input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uml:Model xmi:version="20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_OlYJkC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="model">
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="_OlYJkS9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Activity1" node="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw">
        <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow" source="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow1" source="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_m0Vn8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Timer expired" source="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_wrhvgC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Timer not expired" source="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_Hcj3UC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow2" source="_fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Start" outgoing="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <node xmi:type="uml:OpaqueAction" xmi:id="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Load and Enable Timer" visibility="package" outgoing="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <node xmi:type="uml:DecisionNode" xmi:id="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Has timer expired?" outgoing="_m0Vn8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _wrhvgC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _wrhvgC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
        <node xmi:type="uml:OpaqueAction" xmi:id="_fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Service the Timer ISR" outgoing="_Hcj3UC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_m0Vn8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw">
            <inputValue xmi:type="uml:ActionInputPin" xmi:id="_82lIMDRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" name="interrupt">
                <upperBound xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_82lIMTRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" value="1"/>
            </inputValue>
        </node>
        <node xmi:type="uml:ActivityFinalNode" xmi:id="_F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ActivityFinalNode" incoming="_Hcj3UC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
    </packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

XSLT INPUT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:UML="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns='uri:sadf' exclude-result-prefixes="UML">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/UML:Model">
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sdf3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" type="fsmsadf" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/sdf3/xsd/sdf3-fsmsadf.xsd">
    <applicationGraph name="g">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </applicationGraph>
</sdf3>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="packagedElement">
    <fsmsadf>
    <scenariograph name="sg0" type="t">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
    </scenariograph>
    </fsmsadf>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node">
     <xsl:if test="@'xmi:type'='uml:OpaqueAction'">
         <actor name="{@name}" source="{@outgoing}" />
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output (.XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sdf3 xmlns="uri:sadf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/sdf3/xsd/sdf3-fsmsadf.xsd" type="fsmsadf" version="1.0">
<applicationGraph name="g">
<fsmsadf>
     <scenariograph type="t" name="sg0" />
#Need these lines      <actor name="Load and Enable Timer" source="whatever_input is here">
#Need these lines        <actor name="Service the timer ISR" source="whatever_input is here">
</fsmsadf>
</applicationGraph>
</sdf3>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
<xsl:if test="@'xmi:type'='uml:OpaqueAction'">
```

The correct syntax should be this:

```
<xsl:if test="@xmi:type='uml:OpaqueAction'">
```

You don't need apostrophes around the attribute name. You would only need them to surround a string. You would also need to declare the `xmi` namespace in your XSLT, with the namespace URI matching what is in the XML. If you had tried to run your XSLT, this should have been highlighted in the error message.

Actually, there would been another error before this, as these lines is not valid

```
<xsl:template match="/UML:Model">
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Maybe this is just a typo with your question and that should have been at the start of the XSLT, but if you are actually trying to include the xml declaration in your output XML, you simply need to change `omit-xml-declaration` to "no" on the `xsl:output` element.

Try this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns='uri:sadf'
 xmlns:UML="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" 
 xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701"
 exclude-result-prefixes="UML xmi">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/UML:Model">
    <sdf3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" type="fsmsadf" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/sdf3/xsd/sdf3-fsmsadf.xsd">
    <applicationGraph name="g">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </applicationGraph>
</sdf3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="packagedElement">
    <fsmsadf>
    <scenariograph name="sg0" type="t">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
    </scenariograph>
    </fsmsadf>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
     <xsl:if test="@xmi:type='uml:OpaqueAction'">
         <actor name="{@name}" source="{@outgoing}" />
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```